# Change number in the cell to value from different cell, if it matches the number next to it

Tags: lookup, openoffice-calc

I have is bunch of .csv files, one of them is the main one where I have columns that look something like this:

[image: main doc]

These numbers should be changed to text value which can be found in different file like this one for the `id_type`:

[image: id_type]

So as you can see if in my main I have 199 in `id_type` column - it should look into the other document for number 199 and if found -> take what's in the cell next to it and bring back to the main document and replace 199 with "name199".

Comment: @alex-szabó Can you help me one more time?

What if I now my column that I want data from is a date, and I want the highest date for the my specific id?

Meaning I have a id_name like '123' and it looks up for the date corresponding to this id in column number 3 - but the same id_name has 3 different dates like 2011-10-01, 2012-10-01, 2013-10-01. I want to lookup id_name 123 and return value 2013-10-01 (latest date)

I tried

=VLOOKUP(R2;$Sheet2.$A$2:$C$14995;MAX(C2:C14995)3;0)

But of course it doesn't work...

Comment: @alex-szabó I started a new thread for this question - could you take a look please [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583720/vlookup-search-for-value-and-return-its-latest-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `VLOOKUP()` for this:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2;Sheet2.A2:B6;2;0)
```

`VLOOKUP` (V = Vertical) is a function that will do exactly as you described, the parameters are:

> - What value you wish to find (in this case B2 = 119)
> - Where is the data (in this case the other sheet's A:B range), it is important to note that the value you wish to find in the first step
>     (B2) should be the left-most column of this range.
> - The nth column you wish the retrieve the data from. In your case, you want to return type name, which is the second column (therefore
>     you put 2 in there) of the lookup range.
> - For the last parameter, you should put 0 if you are looking for exact matches (which you do now), and put 1 if you wish to find the
>     closest value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I bet it's exactly what I need but it seems I can't get it right. I have OpenOffice maybe that's why?

I'm trying to figure out why I get error 508 with your first method, and error 501 on your other one

Comment: Maybe it will be faster when instead of looking in other.xls I just paste everything to Sheet2? How to change the formula then?

Comment: @Seb I've updated the answer, Sheet2 is the name of the "other sheet".

Comment: Awesome, that worked! Still trying to figure out how to go about not pasting in Sheet2 and just using the different file but it's pretty much what I needed.
EDIT: Quick question - if the value is not found I get #N/A - how to leave the cell blank instead?

Comment: Wrap it in `ISNA()` like `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B2;Sheet2.A2:B6;2;0));"";VLOOKUP(B2;Sheet2.A2:B6;2;0))`

Comment: Oh one more thing is wrong :/ The first cell looks fine, BUT if I drag the formula down the column - it changes the range! I should have Sheet2.A1:B561 all the way down. But in the lower cell I keep getting .A2:B562, .A3:B563..... :( How to keep it intact??

Comment: @Seb to lock the ranges, change `Sheet2.A2:B6` to `Sheet2.$A$2:$B$6` and try dragging it down then. If you have another question, please post it as a new one, instead of having a long comment conversation. Thanks.